# slam_gmapping Registering First Scan problem

Tags: navigation, odometry, kinect, scan, frames

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(I'm using a custom made robot having wheel encoders and Kinect, and want to implement slam_gmapping)

I have the following /tf set up for my robot:
http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/7405/screenshotat20120423220.png

I added the _1 suffix to the frames I get using my encoders.

I run a pointcloud_to_laserscan launch file which publishes to the /scan topic.
Then I launch gmapping, a clone of the launch file from turtlebot_navigation.

That's when I get the following message:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/10/screenshotat20120423220.png/

And, when I visualize it using rviz, I get a map based on seemingly the very first Laser Scan, after which I can view (visualize) the Laser scan (it moves around as I move the Kinect), but the map doesn't get built further (as it should, iteratively from what I've heard)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/88/screenshotat20120423214.png/

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32399/slam_gmapping-registering-first-scan-problem/) by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-02**:
Why are you adding the _1 suffix to frames from your encoders? What is supplying your base_link->odom transform (the not suffixed versions)? Some other odometry source?

**Comment by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) on 2012-05-02**:
I added the suffix to distinguish it from the *corrected* odom supplied by slam_gmapping, to elicit the encoder errors. However, I don't recall being able to visualize it properly, so I think there's a (logical) flaw in that system. Does slam_gmapping overwrite the odom published by the encoders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having two separate TF trees (which is what is shown in your screenshot) is not correct for a single robot. Your _1 suffix for the frames based on your encoders is the root cause of the issues you have with gmapping. Take a look at [REP 105](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) for some details on standard frames in ROS, but I'll detail how you should fix your frames below.

First off, since your Kinect is connected to the robot's base at some point and doesn't just sort of float, your transform should be between `openni_camera` and `base_link`, not between `openni_camera` and `odom`. Next, your encoders (possibly fused with any other relative type sensors like a gyro or visual odometry using something like `robot_pose_ekf`) should determine the transformation between `base_link` and `odom`. gmapping then publishes the `odom` to `map` transform so that you can localize your robot in the fixed `map` reference frame. You can check that your localization is ready for gmapping if, in `rviz`,  you can set your fixed frame to `odom` and view your `LaserScan` output while driving the robot around. If you set `rviz` to buffer some amount of scans, you should get something that approximates a map of your environment.

gmapping doesn't output a `base_link` to `odom` transform at all (that's what your encoders are generating) - it uses that transform to determine how far your robot has moved between scans. gmapping only outputs the `odom` to `map` transform, so it cannot "overwrite" the `base_link` to `odom` transform.

Once you correct your TF tree, you should be able to use the default gmapping temporal update parameters. You had to enable that to force updates after a certain amount of time because, since your encoders were publishing in a separate TF tree, gmapping was waiting for your robot to move (as indicated by some amount of difference in the `base_link` to `odom` transform, which is what the `linearUpdate` and `angularUpdate` parameters control).

If you want to figure out how much error there is in your odometry from the encoders, you could look at how much the gmapping correction (`odom` to `map` transform) drifts over time. In an ideal situation, and assuming gmapping doesn't move it's origin point while you are mapping, the drift in the `odom` to `map` transform should be zero.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a problem with the gmapping parameters:

~temporalUpdate (float, default: -1.0) // Temporal update disabled!

It works with this:

~temporalUpdate (float, default: 0.1)

These changes need to be made in the gmapping launch file.

---

Originally posted by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) with karma: 115 on 2012-04-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1